# Who benefits from Football Association Fines

Tags: football, finances

The English Football Association, or FA, fine players and managers at all levels of the game for common infractions such as yellow & red cards.

Occasionally players & managers may be disciplined for major infractions such as [making inflamatory remarks on twitter](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/19916978). These fines are usually far more substantial.

My question is - **Who benefits from these fines?** Do they contribute to the operating profits of the FA, or are they invested directly into grass roots sport?

Comment: Some information [*FA Source*](http://www.thefa.com/TheFA/~/media/029E1BAA38934E3C9C4879CF561B38AB.ashx/FAHandbook_Steps2-4.pdf) (from 2009-2010) by the FA on disciplinary procedures they follow. Don't see anything regarding fine money, and how it's used yet.

Comment: Only thing I could scrounge from it about how the fines are used was "(c) *Proceeds of ﬁnes imposed under this section of the Disciplinary Procedures shall be
disbursed as decided by The Football Association*.", page 335 -- which of course helps minimally.

Comment: Which is why this is an important question - if fines counts towards revenue motives become questionable - there is a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 2):

In the FA's [Report and Financial Statements 2012](http://www.thefa.com/~/media/Files/PDF/the-fa-2013-14/fa-report-financial-2012.ashx), on page 18, the 2012 "Other Income" line item on their income statement in the amount of £18 million, includes the disciplinary fines:

> Other income of £18m (2011: £8m) includes income  from tournaments, FA
>   Learning courses, disciplinary  fines, and englandfans membership.

So the fine money is added to the income statement of the FA.  The line item is not broken out further than that on this statement, so I don't know how much of that £18 million is fines.

On page 24, the report lists a total of £14.9 million in charitable donations by the FA for 2012.  I don't know if the two are related, but it is likely that the FA pays out more in charitable donations than it takes in with disciplinary fines.

Comment: So ultimately, you don't know?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra The money goes into the bank account of the FA.  The FA then pays out lots of money for lots of different things (see the linked report for all the details they care to share on expenses).  I'm not aware of any policy of the FA that says "Every pound of disciplinary fine money is spent on X."

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra My point in the last paragraph was that they don't seem to have an explicit policy of donating all fines to charity, but since they apparently donate more to charity than they take in with fines, it's a moot point.

Answer (score -2):

Fines levied on players must be collected by the Club Secretary from the player concerned and forwarded to The Football Association when requested to do so.

Comment: come on I have even put the question in bold

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that it helps towards either funding for certain aspects of the FA, or in another area such as charitable donations etc.

Fining has to be in place for offenses that are not substantial enough for a ban.

I agree the fines are nothing to the footballers, due to there wages but its a good system as the fines must benefit something or they wouldn't be in place